# how can I save data in mobile phone using j2me?

Tags: java-me

How can I save data in mobile phone using j2me?
I want code examples which describes how to store data in mobile phones using j2me.
Further how to give access permission to read/write in mobile phones?

I am using netbeans 6.5 and motorola L6 phone.
Can any one tell me a code example giving how to store, give read/write permission?

Answer (score 6):

You can save data in the [record management store](https://web.archive.org/web/20111108172857/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wi-rms/). There are some limitations though. The biggest one is that only your application will be able to read the data.

An alternative is to use the FileConnection API, which offers access to the device's file system. All modern phones should support it. However, unless the Midlet is signed, the user will be nagged to give permission to access a file.

Answer (score 1):

Use the PDAPDemo example code from the Sun Wireless Toolkit.

Last time I checked it had a few error handling bugs but it is easily modifiable.

It will tell you what parts of the handset file system your application can read from and write to, both on the phone and on any eventual memory card.